# Capturing the xpath of a textbox generated by javascript using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

In my application I have a button where in if i click a javascript pop up comes up with a textbox to enter the name of the task and an Ok and Cancel button.During automaing this i need to capture the xpath of the textbox in order to enter the task name. Please someone help me to do this.

Comment: Show us the HTML around the text box.

Comment: <div id="">
<div id="msg" class="" style="display: none;">
<span class="msg-text" onclick="toggleMsgDetails()"></span>
<div class="msg-details"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar-menu">
<span class="menu-owner"> </span>
<span class="bar-delim" style="display:none"> | </span>
<span id="bar_auth">
<span id="bar_public" style="display:none">Public Tasks |</span>
<span id="bar_login">
<a class="nodecor" onclick="showAuth(this);return false;" href="#login">
<u>Login</u>
<img border="0" src="/mytinytodo/themes/default/images/arrdown.gif">
</a>
</span>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "answerOnNextPrompt"?

```
answerOnNextPrompt(answer)
    Arguments:

        answer - the answer to give in response to the prompt pop-up

    Instructs Selenium to return the specified answer string in response to the next JavaScript prompt [window.prompt()].
```